# How to schedule/automate a pyautogui bot on a remote windows server without manually logging in?

Tags: python, automation, airflow, bots, pyautogui

I built a simple `PyAutoGUI` bot script that uses `locateOnScreen` to find an image on my remote windows server desktop and click on it. I want to be able to schedule this to automatically run on said remote windows server ideally through Airflow.

My first  attempt was to schedule via Airflow and SSH into the windows server and execute the script.  This failed as there is no "active display".  If no one is logged into the remote windows server then no screen is produced.

Note I also get the same error when using windows task scheduler.  If I RDP into the server, and manully kick of the task, it works, but if i schedule for a lter time and log out.  When the script is supposed to run, it fails.

Is there a way via software to create a virtual display of some kind or some additional settings on the server or a workaround to be able to execute a pyautogui bot on a remote windows server when not actively logged in?  For the bot to work there needs to be an always on display even when not logged in.

Sample Bot Code:

```
import pyautogui

#initialize image path
image_path = 'path/to/your/image.png'

#find image
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image_path, confidence=0.8)

#move to image
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)

#right click on image
pyautogui.rightClick()
```